# 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

First question, please be gentle :)

I am having trouble creating an index view for a client model that belongs_to the user model with a has_many association.

The error message:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

Specifically the error refers to the partial on line #11:

/views/clients/index.html

```
<% provide(:title, current_user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>Your clients</h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <% if current_user.clients.any? %>
      <ol class="clients">
        <%= render @clients %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

/clients/_client.html.erb

```
<li>
  <span class="client-name"><%= client.name %></span>
  <span class="client-info">
    Extra client info to come.
  </span>
</li>
```

Clients controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  belongs_to :user

  def index
    @clients = current_user.clients.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

EDIT:

Users controller if it helps...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    if current_user.admin?
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    else
        @user = current_user
    end
  end

  def index
    if current_user.admin?
        @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
        User.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
        redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
```

As you can probably tell I am new to rails, but have searched to ensure this hasn't been covered already.

Comment: If you throw a debugger in controller's index method what does @client look like? Also try replacing line 9 in the index view with `<% if @clients.present? %>`.

Comment: I'm using a debugger on the index view which displays `--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
action: index
controller: clients`, unfortunately I don't understand what you mean by a "debugger in the controllers index method". However, I have tried your suggested code on line 9, which shows an empty index. But clients have been generated and are present in the database.

Comment: Update: I am now able to display the correct index by omitting the partial and adding `<% current_user.clients.each do |client| %>; <%= link_to client.name, client %>` but will_paginate now returns `The @clients variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?`

Comment: From what I can understand the instance variable isn't being set properly?

Comment: Right, you want to use @clients for iterating over the rendering of the partial as well as passing it to the will_paginate helper method.

Comment: It *looks* right but there could be other factors. To debug a live application, add ruby-debug to your Gemfile, bundle install, restart the server with --debugger argument on the end. In the index method add a `debugger` line followed by another line like `puts "debugger"`. That last line simply stops the debugger from exiting the method prematurely since it's a one-liner.

Comment: I got an error with that gem so I installed "ruby-debug19" to fix it but when I add the --debugger argument it says `You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode`

Comment: Ok, got "ruby-debug19" working, now when you you say "in the index method", where exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'll make it a one-liner due to comment limitations: `def index; @clients = current_user.clients.paginate(page: params[:page]); debugger; puts "debugger"; end`. Run `rails server --debugger`. When you visit the index page, it'll hit that line and rails server goes into interactive mode. Type `@clients` to see what's doing in your variable.

Comment: It's coming back with the same error `The @clients variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?` I can't load the index when the <%= will_paginate &> is present, I can display a list of clients but with no pagination. I cannot see an interactive mode when the server is loaded with --debugger.

Comment: I've added my users controller just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared belongs_to in the clients controller and the model instead of just the model. And didn't notice for two days.

Comment: Did that fix the problem? I completely missed that. I've used the InheritedResources gem quite a bit so that didn't jump out at me. So much for a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be passing `:page => params[:page]` to paginate instead?

Comment: Thanks @Nick but the current version equals the same just using the new hash symbol I believe.

Comment: Ah sorry - I've not seen it used before but then I do only dabble in ruby.