# Render to partial by Ajax in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have almost done! but I have an issue, in my Controller file have this:

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Then I have this piece of code in my file `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="span8">
   <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
 <% if @user.posts.any? %>
    <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.posts.count %>)</h3>
    <div id='posts'>
      <div class='page'>
     <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @posts %>
     </ol>
  </div>
</div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

At the bottom of this file, I have a Javascript code that I have taken from the tutorial: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery

In the same folder I have the file `index.js.erb` with:

```
$("#articles").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@users)) %></div>");
$("#posts").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@posts)) %></div>");
```

In a partial `_posts.html.erb` have this:

```
<div class='article'>
  <%= image_tag(user.picture_url, :width => 50) %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The first one already works in my file `index.html.erb`, the problem is with the second piece of code, when I try to render the partial at `@post`, It brings the follow log:

```
**
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
Extracted source (around line #2):
1: $("#articles").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@users)) %></div>");
2: $("#posts").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@posts)) %></div>");
**
```

How can I render that partial?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Is the line `I need to render to the "_feed_item.html.erb" inside "_feed.html.erb"` means you are already in the `_feed.html.erb` page and just want to load more `_feed_item.html.erb` when user scrolls down to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, you got it!, how can i do that?

Comment: are you using rails 2.x.x or 3.x.x ?

Comment: Also let us know some more details like which js library u r using etc. I will try to make a dummy app for you.

Comment: by the way I'm using rails 3.2.8

Comment: it means rendering `@user` is working fine but problem with `@posts`

Comment: just wanted to confirm that you dont have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985782/1160106

Comment: Another thing is while you are loading more items, are you calling `show` function or `/feed_items?page=' + page` ? You can put a log inside your show method to see if it gets `nil` while loading more items.

Comment: In script I'm calling to /users?page=, and I was wondering that It may calls the line ": $("#posts").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@posts)) %></div>");"

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the .js.erb template to render the partial into a var then set it on the page using JS.  Be sure to escape_javascript the template content otherwise you will get JS errors.

```
<% template_html = render :partial => '_feed_item.html.erb' %>
<%="$('div#content').html('#{escape_javascript(template_html)}</div>');" %>
```

I think the above should work in erb. I use HAML so mine looks like:

```
-template_html = render :partial => 'partial_template'
!="$('div#content').html('#{escape_javascript(template_html)');"
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `In script I'm calling to /users?page=, and I was wondering that It may calls the line`, you must make sure that your controller is populating the `@posts` variable if your view is using this. Can you show the controller method `users`?

Comment: users?page script is inside the show.html.erb, so in the controller I have this:     def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

Comment: You have a `def users ... .. end` method right? Would you please add that in your post? This method must populate `@posts` also.

Comment: Ups, i don't have defined that method, but it works with the show method @user :s

Comment: I've done! I must replace one render, because of the abstract function, but now it works! thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you share your final code here. That might help others. Well I dont know i really deserve the accept or not :)